# Reverse Holder functions

Tags: analysis, continuity, dimension-theory-analysis, holder-spaces

For a function defined on $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$, we call it reverse-Holder with exponent $\alpha >0$ if there exists some $c > 0$ such that
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \geq c|x-y|^\alpha. $$
The definition can be useful when studying the Hausdorff dimension, for instance see [Reverse Hölder Continuity and Hausdorff dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/374905/525906).

However, while Holder-continuous functions are ubiquitous, reverse-Holder functions seems hard to imagine. Intuitively, reverse Holder condition states that the function has to be highly-irregular/rough everywhere in the domain. How does one construct such a function? Can it still be continuous or even Holder continuous?

P.S. When I think of rough functions, I think of things like sample path of Brownian motion and Weierstrass function. However, I believe none of them are reverse holder.

Comment: For an example in $[0,1]$, you will need $\alpha \ge 1$.  So, for example, the function $f(x) = x$ satisfies $|f(x)-f(y)| \ge |x-y|^2$ for $x,y \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you! But does there exists an example for $\alpha < 1$?

Comment: In Euclidean space, no $\alpha < 1$ is not possible.  In other metric spaces, it could be possible.